# Which settings or priveleges user needs for using NetworkManager.Settings.Connection

Tags: linux, qt, dbus

I've tried to call the method GetSettings of the D-Bus object org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection by the path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2 (the number of settings just for example) in the Qt application. So when I tried to run this application as user with

```
$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),
46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
```

it worked fine without errors, but when I'd started the application as lightdm greeter (lightdm user starts process) it logged the error:

```
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.PermissionDenied uid 108 has no permission
to perform this operation
```

I've tried to make it with org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
  "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
 <busconfig>
         <policy user="root">
                 <allow own="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.PPP"/>

                 <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.SecretAgent"/>
                 <!-- These are there because some broken policies do
                 <deny send_interface="..." /> (see dbus-daemon(8) for details).
                 This seems to override that for the known VPN plugins.
                   -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openswan"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.ssh"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.iodine"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.libreswan"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.fortisslvpn"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.strongswan"/>
                 <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin"/>

                 <!-- Allow the custom name for the dnsmasq instance spawned by NM
                      from the dns dnsmasq plugin to own it's dbus name, and for
                      messages to be sent to it.
                  -->
                 <allow own="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq"/>
         </policy>
         <policy user="whoopsie">
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active"/>

                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device"/>
         </policy>
         <policy context="default">
                 <deny own="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>

                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>

            <!-- Basic D-Bus API stuff -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>

            <!-- Devices (read-only properties, no methods) -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Adsl"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Bond"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Bridge"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Bluetooth"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wired"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Generic"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Gre"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Infiniband"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Macvlan"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Modem"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.OlpcMesh"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Team"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Tun"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Veth"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Vlan"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.WiMax.Nsp"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint"/>

            <!-- Devices (read-only, no security required) -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.WiMax"/>

            <!-- Devices (read/write, secured with PolicyKit) -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device"/>

            <!-- Core stuff (read-only properties, no methods) -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.DHCP4Config"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.DHCP6Config"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.IP4Config"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.IP6Config"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection"/>

            <!-- Core stuff (read/write, secured with PolicyKit) -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings"/>
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection"/>

            <!-- Agents; secured with PolicyKit.  Any process can talk to
                 the AgentManager API, but only NetworkManager can talk
                 to the agents themselves. -->
                 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                        send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AgentManager"/>

            <!-- Root-only functions -->
                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_member="SetLogging"/>
                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_member="Sleep"/>
                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings"
                       send_member="LoadConnections"/>
                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings"
                       send_member="ReloadConnections"/>

                 <deny own="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq"/>
                 <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq"/>
         </policy>

    <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">1024</limit>
    <limit name="max_match_rules_per_connection">2048</limit>
 </busconfig>
```

Could you help me make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403366/which-settings-or-privileges-user-needs-for-using-networkmanager-settings-connec ?